Equivalent definitions of Cantor-Bendixson Rank
Yesterday I asked this question: Derived set of a closed subspace
The motivation of my question is that I am studying the notion of Cantor-Bendixson Rank, and I have found two different definitions. I would like to know if both definitions are equivalent.
I will use the following notation: if $A$ is a subset of a topological space $X$, then $A^{(0)}=A$ and $A^{(n+1)}$ is the set of accumulation points of $A^{(n)}$. This can be extended to ordinals, but for what I am going to ask is enough to have the definition for natural numbers.
Let´s start with the first definition. Suppose $X$ is a compact topological space. First we will define the Cantor-Bendixson Rank of a point $a\in X$ as the largest natural number $n$ such that $a\in X^{(n)}$. We will write $\textrm{CBR}_X(a)=n$. Yes, I know that this definition should take into account not only natural numbers but also ordinals, but for the moment we may assume that the Cantor-Bendixson Rank is always finite. If $A$ is a non-empty closed subset of $X$, we will say that the Cantor-Bendixson Rank of $A$ is $n$ if $n$ is the largest natural number for which there is some $a\in A$ with $\textrm{CBR}_X(a)=n$. So $\textrm{CBR}_X(A)=n$ if and only if $A\cap X^{(n)}\neq\emptyset$ and $A\cap X^{(n+1)}=\emptyset$.
The second definition consists on defining the Cantor-Bendixson Rank of a closed subset $A$ of $X$ as the Cantor-Bendixson Rank of the topological space $A$ with the inherited topology, that is, the largest natural number $n$ for which $A^{(n)}$ is non-empty (calculated as a topological space itself, with the inherited topology). This makes sense, because $A$ is again compact.
I cannot prove that the two definitions of $\textrm{CBR}_X(A)$ are equivalent, but I am studying some model theory (where Cantor-Bendixson Rank is important) and the definition used depends on the author. Are both definitions equivalent, at least, under some assumptions?

The definitions are equivalent assuming $A$ is clopen. Since you're studying model theory,  you're probably interested in the case when $A$ is the basic clopen set in the Stone space of types corresponding to a formula, right?

More or less. I start with a stable formula $\varphi$ and a complete $\varphi$-type $p$ over a small set of parameters. Now, I consider the set $X$ of complete global $\varphi$-types which are extensions of $p$. And the thing is that the non-forking extensions of $p$ are the elements of $X$ of maximal CB-rank. The problem is that Pillay (in Geometric Stability Theory) uses the second definition of my question, while books like “Simple theories and hyperimaginaries” use the first one. But they are not equivalent in general… I must be missunderstanding something.

Ah, yes. I think this is a bit of an "xy problem" - it would have been more efficient to ask your actual underlying model theory question to begin with. The definition in Pillay's GST (Definition 1.3.2 at the bottom of p. 31) is either wrong or confusingly worded - interpreted literally, as you did, it differs from standard practice in model theory, and it makes basic properties of the rank (like Lemma 1.3.3(ii) and (v)) false. I have been confused about this before! See here.

Uh that makes sense!

They are not equivalent as definitions. Consider the space $X=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{1}{n+1}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ with the standard topology and let $A=\{0\}\subseteq X$. We have that $X^{(0)}=X$, $X^{(1)}=\{0\}$, and $X^{(2)}=\emptyset$. Now according to the first definition we have:
\begin{equation}
\text{CBR}(A)=\max\{\text{CBR}_X(x):x\in A\}=\text{CBR}_X(0)=1
\end{equation}
We have that $A^{(0)}=\{0\}$ and $A^{(1)}=\emptyset$ so by the second definition we have that:
\begin{equation}
\text{CBR}(A)=\max\{\alpha\in Ord: A^{(\alpha)}\neq \emptyset\}=0
\end{equation}
So the two definitions do not coincide.
The issue is that in general a limit point of $X$ may not be a limit point of $A$ and so $A'$ is not the same thing as $X'\cap A$. This means that points that have very high rank in $X$ can have very low rank in $A$.
